# How to turn this string into a DateTime

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse the following string to a DateTime object:

```
20/06/24,17:05:12+08
```

I tried the following to no avail.

```
var parsedToDateTime = DateTime.Parse("20/06/24,17:05:12+08");

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(latestDate, "yy/MM/dd,HH:mm:ss%K", null,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine(parsedDate);
}

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(latestDate, "yy/MM/dd,HH:mm:sszzz", null,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
{
    Console.WriteLine(parsedDate);
}
```

Comment: Use only two _zz_ in the latest test

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20/06/24,17:05:12+08", "dd/MM/yy,HH:mm:sszz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It should work.

You were using `zzz` which translates to `+08:00`, so `zz` will map from `+08`. :)

Here there's all formats that are accepted:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings